# How are data science and cryptography related?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

Are there any interesting connections between the fields of data science and cryptography?

Data science involves the use of statistical analysis to analyze data while cryptography also involves statistics in crypt-analysis in order to protect data. And of course both fields require a lot of math.

So I wonder if there are any interesting links between these two fields.

Comment: Information theory is the parent field, with deep ties to physics. Cryptography is a subset under it involving a variety of techniques involving data security. Data science is a more general field around finding interesting ways to analyze data and various efficient algorithms. Cryptography sometimes uses these algorithms.

Comment: @Natanael: Cryptography uses mathematics, not data science.

Comment: is data science a science?

Comment: @mentallurg I was probably thinking of computer science rather than data science (I blame my native language, "computer" = "dator"). But data science techniques is still relevant in subfields of cryptography such as privacy preserving techniques like for databases, analytics and anonymization. Side channel resistance and more requires that analytical techniques can't extract sensitive data.

Comment: I think the most honest answer is: "They are not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by data science, you mean "machine learning and cie", there is some recent works that made the link between these two hot topics :

For example, some people are trying to do data analysis on encrypted data : https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1114

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for examples of interesting connections than my favorite is using Genearative adverserial networks (GANs) in order to invent novel cryptographic primitives.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06918